# Spring Native memory related issues

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I want to know if I use Spring-Native, do I still need to configure what garbage collector to use, how much heap memory to set and other JVM startup parameters, do I not need to configure any of these at all? If so, then the actual memory occupied by the application is the actual memory used and no more space will be opened up in advance because of setting the heap size?